# Где посмотреть, сколько весит файл, прошедший gzip-сжатие?

Tags: nginx, google-chrome, gzip

Привет. Где посмотреть, до какого размера gzip сжал размер файла? Во вкладке Network в Google Dev Tools виден исходный размер файла.

**UPD:** в Google Chrome есть два параметра, отображающие размер файла и количество байт, переданных по сети. Однако, у меня этот параметр не отображается, хотя сжатие включено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте версию хрома и ОС

Comment: проверьте, что у вас включено сжатие

Answer (score 2):

В **Network** на против каждого запроса есть 2 цифры:

1. Количество байт переданных по сети
2. Размер содержимого

Вот что показывает **Network** для этого вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое и есть размер сжатого потока.

У меня **Chrome Version 59.0.3071.104 (Official Build) (64-bit)** для Mac OS

Comment: Странно, но у меня этого не происходит. Хотя, сжатие включено и сайты, тестирующие состояние gzip говорят о том, что сжатие включено. http://i.imgur.com/tQZ16ke.png